# Computer Shut Off Python 3.4

Tags: macos, python-3.x, system-shutdown

A friend of mine wants to automatically shut off his computer using Python 3.4 (to put in a program). Does anyone know a basic as-small-as-possible way to do this?

OS:
Mac OSX Yosemite

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OS X is a Unix at its base, so you can use Unix commands. you can use either:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
os.system("shutdown -h now")
```

Must be run as root, won't work otherwise. You can however add to sudoers (`man visudo`) `shutdown` as `NOPASSWD` program for the users that want to execute the script and use `sudo shutdown …` instead of just `shutdown…`

or

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['osascript', '-e',
'tell app "System Events" to shut down'])
```

Comment: So easy and so much advantages for programming my trading system backtests! Thank you.