# How can I shut down my computer using python script?

Tags: python

I want to shut down my computer(mac) using a python script for some code I have written. I have tried the following

```
os.system('shutdown -s')
os.system('shutdown -h now')
```

But both of these produce the output 256 and my system doesn't shut down.

I read it might be due to not having root privileges but I guess I can't provide root privileges through python. Is there a way I can run a python script and shut down my mac with the above problem ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/28438311/5559590

Answer (score 1):

For restart:

```
re_start = ["shutdown", "-f", "-r", "-t", "30"]
```

For shutdown:

```
 shut_down = ["shutdown", "-f", "-s", "-t", "30"]
```

Hence:

```
def shutdown(self):
    import subprocess
    subprocess.call(shut_down)
```